# Comparing 2 dictionaries: same key, mismatching values

Tags: python

I am currently trying to compare 2 data sets:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':4}
```

In this case I want the output to be something like:

```
set1 = set([('c', 4), ('c',3)])
```

since their keys match but values do not.

I've tried a variation of  comprehensions using the intersection and difference operators but I cannot get the desired output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible: a dictionary key cannot appear twice.  Would you be happy with a list of pairs (tuples), perhaps?

Comment: Do you want that to be the *printed* output, or do you want an object to be returned that prints exactly that way, or do you want an object that is just *similar* to dict3?

Comment: Dicts have, by definition, unique keys.

Comment: @Prune thanks for pointing that out. Forgot about that little detail :). I've changed the original post so that my question makes more sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Python 2:

```
dict1.viewitems() ^ dict2.viewitems()
```

If you are using Python 3:

```
dict1.items() ^ dict2.items()
```

`viewitems` (Python 2) and `items` (Python 3) return a set-like object, which we can use the caret operator to calculate the symetric difference.

Comment: By far the most efficient approach. No unnecessary sets created

Comment: @PadraicCunningham wouldn't `dict1.viewitems().symmetric_difference(dict2.items())` be slightly more efficient (in Python 2)?

Comment: @PeterWood `dict1.viewitems()` returns a set-like object, but not a set object. Thus, it does not have the `symetric_difference` method.

Comment: For Python 2 would `set(dict1.items()).symmetric_difference(dict2.items())` be most efficient? I will do some tests.

Comment: @PeterWood. From a memory perspective definitely not, as far as speed goes I would imagine the same would hold True

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've updated my answer with some timings for Python 2. I think the answer here is the most readable and close enough to the most efficient. Surprisingly, to me, the fastest was `set(dict1.viewitems()).symmetric_difference(dict2.viewitems())`

Answer (score 5):

```
set(dict1.items()).symmetric_difference(dict2.items())
```

Use `iteritems` in Python 2 for better efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `MultiDict`.  They don't exist in the standard library for python, but the popular [`boltons`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dictutils.html#boltons.dictutils.OrderedMultiDict) package has them.  They allow you to store multiple keys in the same field.

```
from boltons.dictutils import MultiDict

dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':4}

m = MultiDict()
for k in dict1.keys():
    if dict1.get(k) != dict2.get(k):
        m.add(k, dict1.get(k))
        m.add(k, dict2.get(k))

print m
for k in m.keys():
    print k, m.getlist(k)

# OrderedMultiDict([('c', 3), ('c', 4)])
# 'c' [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Python. Dictionaries are data structures which have **unique** keys, so you cannot have the same key twice in the same dictionary, no matter what the value is.

As an alternative, you may want to produce a list of tuples (key, value) for each duplicated key.

```
l = [(k,v,k,dict2[k]) for k,v in dict1 if k in dict2]
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot about that. The output can be in a tuple pair.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the dictionaries into sets of pairs; take the set difference both ways and merge the lists:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':4}

set1 = set([(k, v) for k, v in dict1.items()])
set2 = set([(k, v) for k, v in dict2.items()])
diff_set = list(set1 - set2) + list(set2-set1)
print diff_set
```

Output:

```
[('c', 3), ('c', 4)]
```

---

EDIT per Peter Wood's observations:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':4}

set1 = set(dict1.items())
set2 = set(dict2.items())
diff_set = set1 ^ set2
print diff_set
```

Comment: Why the list comprehension and not a generator expression? Why not just `set(dict1.items())`, etc? Why not use `set ^ set`?

Comment: My answer is overkill, for visibility and maintainability.  Your suggestions will improve execution and make the code shorter; they're more Pythonic.  I'll edit a second set with your updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for key, val in dict1.iteritems():
   if key in dict2 and val != dict2[key]:
     set1.add((key, val))

 for key, val in dict2.iteritems():
   if key in dict1 and val != dict1[key]:
     set1.add((key, val))
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets you fairly close:

```
for value in zip(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    if(value[0] != value[1]):
        tuple = value
print tuple
```

(('c', 3), ('c', 4))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and take the [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference):

```
set(dict1.items()) ^ set(dict2.items())
```

**edit**: I looked into the performance on Python 2, using [**`timeit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Fastest is **`set(dict1.viewitems()).symmetric_difference(dict2.viewitems())`**.

Close second, and most readable is **`dict1.viewitems() ^ dict2.viewitems()`**

Worst is my answer **`set(dict1.items()) ^ set(dict2.items())`**:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> setup = ('dict1 = {str(i): i for i in range(1000)}; '
...          'dict2 = {str(i): (i if i % 10 else i - 1) for i in range(1000)}')
```

This gives us two dictionaries with `1000` entries and `10%` different, i.e. `200` symmetric difference:

```
>>> exec(setup)
>>> len(dict1.viewitems() ^ dict2.viewitems())
200
```

We're going to check each case 30000 times:

```
>>> def check(expression):
...     return timeit(expression, setup, number=30000)
```

The timings, best to worst:

```
>>> check('set(dict1.viewitems()).symmetric_difference(dict2.viewitems())')
8.233164442241105

>>> check('dict1.viewitems() ^ dict2.viewitems()')
8.242523450809585

>>> check('set(dict1.viewitems()).symmetric_difference(dict2.items())')
8.651751725357371

>>> check('set(dict1.items()).symmetric_difference(dict2.items())')
8.774394999897368

>>> check('set(dict1.items()) ^ set(dict2.items())')
9.795530728021276
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer but I suspect slower since it constructs an extra set.

Comment: @AlexHall yes, it's probably slower.